# Как удалить из строки все последующие повторяющиеся слова?

Tags: java

Не получается удалить из строки все последующие повторяющиеся слова, оставляя только первые слова. Пробовала и с использованием массива, добралась до регулярных выражений. Я только учусь, поэтому прошу помощи разобраться.

```java
public static String removeConsecutiveDuplicates(String s) {
 
    String str = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(\\b\\w+\\b)(.*?) \\b\\1\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        s = m.replaceAll("$1$2");
        m = p.matcher(s);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

частое выражение `(?i)(\b\w+\b)(.*?) \b\1\b` находит все повторяющиеся слова. Но мне нужно чтобы первое вхождение не удалялось.
Например строка пришла :

```
"alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta"
```

Мне нужен вывод после работы моей программы

```
"alpha beta gamma delta alpha beta gamma delta"
```

Мой код выводит

```
alpha beta gamma delta
```

Как мне вообще лучше добиться достижения результата?

Comment: 1) разбить строку на массив слов 2) убрать дубликаты из массива (можно фильтрануть через хешсет) 3) собрать из отфильтрованных слов новую строку

Comment: Да, я делала так, но увы это не сработала для меня. Все тесты не проходят.

Answer (score 1):

Для обнаружения слов, следующих друг за другом, нужно использовать обратные ссылки `\1`, так что результата можно достичь достаточно простым выражением.  Может понадобиться два прохода, чтобы корректно обработать повторения в начале и конце строки.

```java
public static String removeConsecutiveWords(String str) {
    return str
        .replaceAll("(?i)(\\b\\w+\\W+)(\\1)+", "$1")
        .replaceAll("(?i)(\\W*\\w+\\b)(\\1)+", "$1");
}
```

Здесь "слово" определено в первой группе `(\\b\\w+\\W+)` или `(\\W*\\w+\\b)`, а его повторения - при помощи обратной ссылки `(\\1)+` во второй группе, которые соответственно заменяются на первую группу `$1`.

Тест:

```java
String str = "alpha alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta delta";
System.out.println(removeConsecutiveWords(str));
// -> alpha beta gamma delta alpha beta gamma delta
```

---

Также можно использовать классы `\p{L}` (Unicode-буквы) и `\P{L}` (не-буквы) для поиска слов, включающих не только стандартные английские буквы.

```java
public static String removeConsecutiveWords(String str) {
    return str
        .replaceAll("(?i)(\\b\\p{L}+\\P{L}+)(\\1)+", "$1")
        .replaceAll("(?i)(\\P{L}*\\p{L}+\\b)(\\1)+", "$1"); // 
}

String str = "альфа альфа бета бета гамма гамма гамма дельта альфа альфа";
System.out.println(removeConsecutiveWords(str));
// -> альфа бета гамма дельта альфа
```

---

Если между одинаковыми словами могут находиться *разные* последовательности пробельных символов (которые можно игнорировать), то предыдущий подход не сработает, и лучше будет воспользоваться вложенными циклами и `Matcher::find(int start)`:

```java
public static String removeConsecutiveWordsOnly(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\p{L}+)\\b(\\P{L}*)");
    
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    int start = 0;
    while (m.find(start)) {
        String w1 = m.group(1);
        String d1 = m.group(2);
        sb.append(w1).append(d1);
        start = m.end(2);
        while(m.find(start) && w1.equalsIgnoreCase(m.group(1))) {
            start = m.end(2); // пропустить слово и его разделитель
        }
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}
String str = "Alpha alpha;\tальфа альфа\tбета - Бета,БЕТА Delta gamma gamma gamma delta delta";

System.out.println("'" + removeConsecutiveWordsOnly(str) + "'");
// -> 'Alpha альфа бета - Delta gamma delta '
System.out.println("'" + removeConsecutiveWords(str) + "'");
// -> 'Alpha alpha; альфа альфа бета - Бета,БЕТА Delta gamma delta'
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за детальное объяснение, но не сработало по всем тестам.

Comment: Прошло все тесты так:                                                             s.replaceAll("(\\b\\S+)( \\1\\b)+", "$1");

Comment: Значит все тесты настроены на то, что слова разделены ровно одним пробелом, ну и определение "слова" как последовательности _любых непробельных_ символов `\S+` достаточно странное.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать именно regex, то можно использовать "опережающие проверки" (positive lookahead) в паре с обратными ссылками.

Задача следующая: ***найти "слово" и если после него идет точно такое же "слово", то удалить его (заменить на "ничего", как дубликат)***

Делается это следующим выражением:

```
(?=(\b\p{L}+\b)\P{L}+\1)\1\P{L}+

что схематически можно представить как:
(?=(WORD)NON_LETTER+\1)\1NON_LETTER+
```

А "расшифровывается" как: найти позицию в строке (сохранив при этом слово `WORD` как `\1`), после которой `WORD` идет за `WORD` (разделённый через `NON_LETTER+`) и если такая позиция есть - матчим первый `WORD` из двух

Таким образом у нас выйдет (Y - match, N - no match):

```
alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta
↑N    ↑Y   ↑N   ↑Y    ↑Y    ↑N    ↑N    ↑N    ↑Y   ↑N   ↑Y    ↑Y    ↑N    ↑N
```

И мы просто можем удалить все попадания через `return s.replaceAll(PATTERN, "");`

https://regex101.com/r/rW0aHo/1

Comment: Спасибо за вашу подсказку. Вроде бы разобралась в данной теме.